# Using jQuery for ajax call once url is entered in input field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a script that I wrote in PHP which scrapes data from a url.

Is it possible with jQuery to do an ajax call that, once a url is entered into an input field (There is a URL validation inside the script), it "Loads" until a successful url has been identified and the rest of the script can then run thus returning results once it is complete.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to describe:

[image]

What exactly should I look up to understand how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').keyUp(function(){
        var v = $(this).val(); // Value currently in search box

        if(v.length) $('#loader').show();
        else $('#loader').hide();

        var r = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/ // Regex Pattern
        if(r.test(v)) { // Yes, a valid url
            // Do your $.ajax({}); request here
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
<p id="loader">Loading...</p>
```

Comment: @bob_cobb that's great I'm glad it'll help you. Remember to tick the answer you found most helpful.

Comment: I'm playing with the code right now, and for some reason, when testing and I enter a valid url and put this in the if(r.test(s)) conditional `$("#loading").html("text can include html code");`, and it didn't load the text. Does that have to be inside of an $.ajax({}); request? I'm trying to understand how this works. Thanks.

Comment: @bob_cobb Oops! my bad. It should be `if(r.test(v))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve?
You could add an event handler for the "KeyUp" event on your input box, and then query your PHP script through AJAX on every KeyUp event, and just show some kind og "Loading" message until your script returns something useful.

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks a bunch, I'm going to use Emmanuel's example above to play around with this. jQuery noob, but learning more every day. Thanks for telling me exactly what I should be looking for (event handling for the KeyUp event). +1 for "og 'Loading'" message. Ha.

Answer (score 0):

First look up a) how to REGEX urls. There's URL Regexes. Google 'em! At the same time, look how REGEXing is done in JS.

b) Look up how you subscribe to `input type="text"` events the jQuery way. (ex: `$.("#textbox1").bind('change', function(ev) {doTheFiltering();});`. I can't look it up now, I am on a very slow connection)

Then, c) the jQuery.Get() command from jQuery. It shows you how you get html, json, whatever back.